# Can't run my Django app on hosting with Debug = False

Tags: python, django

I tried running my Django app on hosting, but when i typed

```
python manage.py runserver
```

with DEBUG = False, it threw me an error:

```
Error: That IP address can't be assigned to.
```

After that changed DEBUG to True, but it continued to throw me the same error. What should i do to solve it?

Tried to add my domain in ALLOWED_HOSTS, didnt work. Put 127.0.0.1 and localhost - same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: python manage.py runserver run with local host ip and port. Add your own ip and port. Like below. `python manage.py runserver ip:port`.

Comment: We don't know what IP Address you tried using, but there could be another instance of your `python manage.py runserver` running or the port could be in use and you may have to change it (I don't know if django makes the distinction between the port or ip address being busy). Assuming you're on linux, you can check to see what other instances of python are running with `ps` shell command, then kill them with `kill task_id -9` or another application could be running on that port and ip address - you'd have to google what command will check for that and then use grep to find it.